# The Inverse of the Euler Totient Function

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, arithmetic-functions

How can we calculate the cardinality of the inverse of Totient function of any positive integer n ?
I tried going through this [paper](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=inverse%2520of%2520euler%2520totient%2520gupta&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.new.dli.ernet.in%252Frawdataupload%252Fupload%252Finsa%252FINSA_2%252F20005a81_22.pdf&ei=ptx4UKLpO4_OrQf934CoDA&usg=AFQjCNEKBequrFgs77Sy4fMaSdv26NmCRA&sig2=w8i0QuwLcMU54WKnYyoeWA), but I couldn't understand the procedure.

Thanks

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: The correct link: http://www.new.dli.ernet.in/rawdataupload/upload/insa/INSA_2/20005a81_22.pdf

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are asking about $N(m)$, the number of distinct integers $n$ which satisfy $\phi(n)=m$ where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient function.

There are many results regarding upper and lower bounds for the size of $N(m)$, as well as the mean and variance.  In particular, Carmichael conjectured that $N(m)$ is never equal to $1$.

Pomerance gave the upper bound $$N(m)\leq  m\exp{-(1+o(1))\log m \frac{\log \log \log m}{\log \log m}}$$ and also showed that there are infinitely many $m$ for which $$N(m)\geq m^{\frac{5}{9}}.$$

Bateman showed that $$\sum_{m\leq x} N(m)=\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}x+O\left(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x\log \log x}}\right),$$ and we also have that $$\sum_{m\leq x} N(m)-\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}x=\Omega\left(x^\frac{5}{9}\right)$$

For more details, see the following paper of Pomerance: [Popular Values of Euler's Function](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/popular.pdf).

Comment: thanks Eric, but for calculations what's o(1) ? 

Answer (score 3):

See also my recent paper ["Computing the (number or sum of) inverses of Euler's totient and other multiplicative functions"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6054), which presents a generic dynamic programming algorithm for finding the inverses of a multiplicative function for a given integer value.

Please let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: I liked your preprint. I would like it more if you gave a gentler introduction to your main equation (the one with the big O symbols) and defined or set up more components before displaying the equation.  One way that might work is to claim and write down an equation for Min, then say Min is a context and that the Min example is a special case of, and then present the general form.  My mind appreciates a graspable example just before a syntactically similar generalization.

Comment: @The Masked Avenger: Thank you for insightful comments. This preprint was composed in rush (for a conference submission) and I plan to improve it significantly in further revisions.

Comment: This impresses me as a (potentially very instructive) example of applied category theory.  Even if it turns out to be an instance of something that (say) Michael Barr wrote up some time ago, I could see this as motivation to learn more category theory.

Comment: I've just posted an updated version to arxiv. Please let me know if it addresses your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

f you are interested in a computational approach, there is software that can compute
$\varphi^{-1}(n)$.

[PARI/GP Scripts for Miscellaneous Math Problems by Max Alekseyev](http://www.cse.sc.edu/~maxal/gpscripts/)
check invphi.gp.

The original invphi.gp appears for quite old pari/gp and doesn't run on current pari,
I ported it [here](http://drememi.ludost.net/invphi2.gp).

Here is a sample session:

```
? \r invphi2.gp 
? n=2*13*17;v=invphi(n);#v
%1 = 2
? v
%2 = [443, 886]
? eulerphi(v[1])==n
%3 = 1
```

Comment: I've tested invphi.gp on PARI/GP 2.6.2 and it works fine. Could you please tell me what exactly the problem you are experiencing with my code? Thanks!

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I suppose I backported it to older pari/gp for backwards compatibility (pari/gp versions are not fully compatible and the code didn't work for me at the time). Your code indeed works on new pari/gp.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should also take a look at
[This OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A014197), and to the references within.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive attempt, which can be refined to give an upper bound on the cardinality.
 I will only look at the case that the inverse n is odd, the even case being mildly more
complicated.

So given $p$, I want to find how many odd $n$ satisfy $\phi(n)=p$.  Let $p=r2^w$ with $r$
odd.  To make things interesting assume $w>0$.  Pick $b \geq w$ and assume $n$ has at most
$b$ factors. Place the  $w$ 2's in $b$ buckets. If a prime factor $q$ of $r$ is not going into a bucket,
then we must put in one bucket enough to make $q-1$.  Otherwise,  distribute the prime factors
of $r$ into the buckets. Each bucket will contain those primes which multiply to form $q-1$, where
$q$ is a factor of $n$.  If $r$ has $c$ not necessarily distinct prime factors,
there are then at most $c^{b+1}$
ways to distribute the factors of $r$, and not all of them will work.

A recursive version is to assume the least prime factor of  $n$ is $q$, and then try to find solutions
to $\phi(m)=p/[(q-1)q^s]$ for appropriate values of $s$.  This may be quicker to implement but harder
to analyze.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.12