# Solutions to phi(x) phi(y) = constant

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry

Let $\phi(x)$ be [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function): The number
of positive integers at most $x$ and relatively prime to $x$.
Solutions to the equation
$$ \phi(x) \, \phi(y) = c $$
where $c \in \mathbb{N}$ is a constant approximate a hyperbola,
which is not surprising because $\phi(x) \, \phi(y) = \phi(x y )$
(when $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime).
For example, for $c=48$, solutions include 
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(2) \, \phi(210) & = & 1 \cdot 48 \\
\phi(7) \, \phi(15) & = & 6 \cdot 8 \\
\phi(10) \, \phi(26) & = & 4 \cdot 12
\end{eqnarray}
and here is a plot of solutions:

---

[image: c=48]

---

For $c=72$, a solutions plot looks like this:

---

[image: c=72]

---

My question is:

> ***Q***. Have the solutions to $\phi(x) \, \phi(y) = c$ been detailed / enumerated / thoroughly described?

Likely the answer is *Yes*, in which case pointers would be appreciated.
In lieu of a detailed enumeration, qualitative descriptions would be useful:
e.g., curves that sandwich solutions from below and from above.

---

Where this question arose. I was thinking of connecting every point 
$(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, gcd$(x,y)=1$, to its "number-theoretic cousins"
(and then studying the properties of the resulting graph).
One notion of cousin-hood might be the same $\phi(x y)$ value. Which led me
to the posed ***Q***.

Comment: Have the solutions of $\phi(x)=c$ been detailed? Since $\phi$ is multiplicative only on coprime numbers, your question appears to be more general than that, but perhaps only superficially so, since it boils down to the divisors of $c$. In other words, one only needs to study $\phi(x)=d$ for $d|c$.

Comment: @July: Point taken. Even bounds on the shape of the solutions-region would be interesting. (Question so edited.)

Comment: Your links for c=48,72 seem defunct (at least on my machine)

Comment: $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ holds when $\gcd(x,y)=1$, and a few other instances; e.g., $\phi(4)\neq\phi(2)\phi(2)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: It is also true that $\phi(x)$ resembles $x.$ Lower bounds are achieved at the primorial numbers, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below/301856#301856 and my other answer there

Comment: Hardy and Wright, Theorem 330, the average order of $\phi(n)$ is $Cn,$ where the constant $C = 6 / \pi^2$

Comment: @WillJagy: Ah, yes, the ubiquitous $6/\pi^2$: [What fraction of the integer lattice can be seen from the origin?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/151706/6094).

Comment: Yeah. I think, for your question, the fact that only relatively rare cases have $\phi(n)$ much smaller than $n$ say that you are going to get hyperbolas, with perhaps some extra  fuzziness in the middle

Comment: @WillJagy: Agreed. I would be interested to quantify the "fuzziness."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider first the problem of finding the set $S_c=\{n\mid \phi(n)=c\}.$ After all, the set of $(x,y)$ with $\phi(x)\phi(y)=c$ will include all the points $(n,1)$ with $n \in S_c$ and they all lie on different hyperbolas. There are also the points $(n,2).$ The points with $\phi(x)\phi(y)=c$ are the union of the various rectangles $S_{c_1}\times S_{c_2}$ over all solution of $c_1c_2=c.$

Everything in $S_c$ has the form $n=q_1^{e_1}\cdots q_s^{e_s}p_1\cdots p_t$ where the $q_i$ are prime divisors of $c$  and the $p_j$ are distinct primes with $p_j-1\mid c.$ So it is a matter of finding all such possible $p$ and doing an organized search to obtain all the solutions. This is a rough description. For example, if $29^2 \mid c$ then one might be able to use $29^2$ or $29^3$ in the front provided that $2^27=28 \mid c. $ Otherwise, to get the $17^2$, one would need to make use of either two unequal primes such as $p=233=8\cdot 29+1$ or one such as $p=10093=12\cdot 29^2+1.$

This is implemented in Maple as **InverseTotient**$(c)$. If I recall correctly, in older versions it was **invphi**$(c)$ and for a while it missed some solutions.

For some good information on this problem check the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109509/the-inverse-of-the-euler-totient-function).

Assuming the current implementation is correct, this make some investigation easy. $c=5760=2^73^25$ is interesting. The primes $p \gt 5$ of the form $d+1$ where $d \mid 5760$ turn out to be $7,11,13,17,19,31,37,41,61,73,97,181,193,241,577,641,1153.$

Maple tells me that  $S_{5760}$ has $129$ elements ranging from  $5917=61\cdot 97$ to $30030=2\ 3\ 5\ 7\cdot 11 \cdot 13.$ This is a ratio of a little over $5.075$ to $1$  and give $129$ points $(n,1)$ which anchor a hyperbola among the points of $\phi(x)\phi(y)=5760.$. The points $(n,2)$ anchor another $102$ hyperbolas.

In all there are (Maple says) $3150$ points belonging to $455$ hyperbolas. Of course some of those "hyperbolas" only have two points. The outer hyperbola is $xy=97020$ with the 4 points $(2310,42),(462,210)$ and their reflections. The hyperbola $xy=30030$ has $64$ points on it (distribute the $6$ prime divisors, some to $x$ and some to $y$) so it goes from $[30030,1]$ to $[1,30030]$ while the $32$ points on $xy=60060$ run from $(30030,2)$ to $(2,30030).$ These are the rightmost and topmost points. This explains why a plot , as in the question, of all $(x,y)$ with $\phi(x)\phi(y)=5760$ looks like the two coordinate axes with fuzz on them.

Here are plots restricted to $\max(x,y) \leq 400$ and $\max(x,y) \leq 800.$ Portions of some of the rectangles $S_{c_1}\times S_{c_2}$ seem discernible. The first has $1500$ points and the second $2718.$ The second thus has a little over $85\%$ of the points. I leave it to you to decide how much it looks like a hyperbola.
[image]

[image]

The graph for $\phi(x)\phi(y)=5760^2$  would include a square of $129^2$ points with corners $(5917,5917)$ and $(30030,30030).$ These are the points with $\phi(x)=\phi(y)=5760.$ This alone gives hyperbolas $xy=m_1$ and $xy=m_2$ with $\frac{m_1}{m_2} \sim 5.075^2 \sim 25.76.$ It appears that there $6025$ hyperbolas intersecting points of that square. There are $6750$ points $(n,1)$ with $\phi(n)=5760^2.$ Of them, $805$ belong to hyperbolas already mentioned and the rest do not.

The outer "hyperbola" is  $xy=30030^2$ with the one point $(30030,30030).$ The inner "hyperbola" is $xy=p=3317761=2^{14}3^45^2+1$ with the two points $(p,1)$ and $(1,p).$

Comment: Insightful analysis---Thanks! Incidentally, Mathematica does not seem to have the equivalent of Maple's InverseTotient( ).

Comment: Turns out Mathematica *does* have InverseTotient, but it is undocumented and not immediately visible (thanks to [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160950/194)): e.g., Reduce`EulerPhiInverse[48] returns {65, 104, 105, 112, 130, 140, 144, 156, 168, 180, 210}.

Answer (score 3):

Some observations to make.

For a prime $p$, let $q=\phi(p)$.  For any solution of $\phi(x)\phi(y)=c$ and for any $p$ dividing $xy$ one has $q$ dividing $c$.  Sometimes $p$ also divides $c$ when $q$ does.

If $x,y$ is a solution then so is $y,x$ also a solution. If $xy$ is odd , then $2x,y$ is another solution, as are obvious variations.  Indeed, if there is a "core" of solution to $c/2^k$, then they can be used by multiplication by $2^k$ or $2^{k+1}$ to form some solutions for $c$, with additional ones possibly given by multiplying by Fermat primes.

Some even numbers like 14 are not values of $\phi$.  Because $7$ and other large odd numbers are also not values, one cannot choose $c=14$ and expect a solution.  However, there may be other values which are not $\phi$ values but may be values for $c$ and have solutions for the equation above.  This might be of interest to the number theory community.

Gerhard "Call Them Rectangular Nontotients, Maybe?" Paseman, 2017.11.25.

Comment: Maybe just understanding for which $c$ is there is at least one solution, would be an advance. E.g., neither $\phi(x) \, \phi(y) = 14$ (your example) nor $=26$ have solutions, despite $c$'s evenness.

Comment: It may be that the parameters are identical, that there is a solution to $\phi(x)\phi(y)=c$ implies that there is a solution to $\phi(x)=c$. But I don't see how to show that.  Gerhard "Can Show The Simpler Direction" Paseman, 2017.11.25.

Comment: $\phi(23)\phi(23)=484$, but there is no solution to $\phi(x)=484$.